# JSF validation for required fields

Tags: jsf, validation

Lets say we have a form with some fields **required** and some not (**optional**).
Now when we say field is required then validator will only validate length of the 
input but won't first **trim** the input and then validate.

To solve this problem i wrote a javascript function called on form submit.
But it will also validate optional fields.

Adding a converter to all the input field is not elegant.
Also is their any way i can override **required** validation process .
Or how can i identify optional input field in **javascript**.

So what is the right way to do this.

using JSF 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register the converter on `<converter-for-class>` instead of `<converter-id>` then it will be applied on all value types.

```
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>java.lang.String</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>com.example.EmptyToNullConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

with

```
public class EmptyToNullConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.trim().length() == 0) {
            if (component instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
                ((EditableValueHolder) component).setSubmittedValue(null);
            }
            return null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.toString();
    }

}
```

No need to register it on every component.